# What makes trippy audiovisuals trippy?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

There are quite a few videos on YouTube (search "trippy videos") that feel "trippy". From what I've heard, some psychedelic artists are just reproducing what they experience when they trip on drugs like LSD.

A few patterns I've noted:

- Other humans/animals looking straight into the camera.
- Looping motion of objects.
- Brilliant colors.

Is there any research into what makes trippy videos trippy? I don't even know if trippiness is supposed to be subjective(in which case, I suppose this question must be closed). Any pointers would be really helpful.

Comment: I guess none of the videos will give you a good picture of the feelings of those that happen to have their schizophrenia started due to use of trips. (relation not scientifically proven but what I see confirms it)

Answer (score 1):

Many of our [associations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_(psychology)) for color, order and music are derived from our culture rather than from biology or some inert psychology. That is to say the bright green house with Christmas lights and tinsel on it all year long might look trippy to you but to the person who designed it it appears to match their society's [norms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(social)).

When you experience the trip its because of the violation of the norm of images your brain has been trained to recognise. The [culture shock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_shock) eventually errodes as you watch the videos more often because your brain begins to learn the patterns and incorporates it into your culture.